# can phantomjs work with node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, coffeescript, phantomjs

I would like to use phantomjs in my node.js script. there is a [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) library.. but unfortunately the author used this weird coffee script code to explain what he's doing:

```
phantom = require 'phantom'

phantom.create (ph) ->
  ph.createPage (page) ->
    page.open "http://www.google.com", (status) ->
      console.log "opened google? ", status
      page.evaluate (-> document.title), (result) ->
        console.log 'Page title is ' + result
        ph.exit()
```

now if I were to use phantomjs directly with javascript, it would look something like [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function (status) {
    var title = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.title;
    });
    console.log('Page title is ' + title);
});
```

so basically I'm trying to write up the equivalent of the first snippet of code above in normal javascript (by reading the coffee script [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#literals).. this is what I did:

```
// file name: phantomTest.js

var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.open('http://www.google.com', function(status) {
            console.log('opened google?', status);
            var title = page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.title;
            });
            console.log('page title is ' + title);              
        });
    });
    ph.exit();
});
```

unfortunately it's not working! If I run

```
node phantomTest.js
```

on the shell, nothing happens.. nothing returns and the process doesn't stop.. any ideas?

**update:**

I just read this in the phantomjs [faq](http://phantomjs.org/faq.html):

> Q: Why is PhantomJS not written as Node.js module?
>
> A: The short answer: "No one can serve two masters."
>
> A longer explanation is as follows.
>
> As of now, it is technically very challenging to do so.
>
> Every Node.js module is essentially "a slave" to the core of Node.js,
>   i.e. "the master". In its current state, PhantomJS (and its included
>   WebKit) needs to have the full control (in a synchronous matter) over
>   everything: event loop, network stack, and JavaScript execution.
>
> If the intention is just about using PhantomJS right from a script
>   running within Node.js, such a "loose binding" can be achieved by
>   launching a PhantomJS process and interact with it.

mmm.. could this have something to do with it? but then that whole library wouldn't make sense!

**update 2:**

I found this code in the [web](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/) that does the same thing:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
      console.log("opened google? ", status);
      return page.evaluate((function() {
        return document.title;
      }), function(result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        return ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

unfortunately that's not working either.. same result!

Comment: Calling something "dumb" because you don't understand how it works and/or you can't make it working in your case is plain rude.

Comment: Also, there's https://github.com/sheebz/phantom-proxy which is more recommended than other Node.js bridges. People have been using bridging PhantomJS with Ruby, PHP, Node.js with varying success.

Comment: I apologize for my strong wording, i'll take it out from the question.. I'll also take a look at `phantom-proxy`.. at the end of th e day my goal is to make things work, it's not to belittle other people's effort.

Comment: This is outdated and should be edited or removed. It doesn't reflect the latest phantomjs-node package and it's capabilities.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

phantomjs-node isn't an official supported npm package for phantomjs. Instead, it implements a "nauseously clever bridge" between node and phantom by creating a web server that uses websockets to serve as an IPC channel between node and phantom. [I'm not making this up](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#no-really-how-does-it-work):

> So we communicate with PhantomJS by spinning up an instance of ExpressJS, opening Phantom in a subprocess, and pointing it at a special webpage that turns socket.io messages into alert() calls. Those alert() calls are picked up by Phantom and there you go!

So I wouldn't be surprised if phantomjs-node works, doesn't work, fails silently, or fails spectacularly. Nor would I expect anyone other than the author of phantomjs-node to be able to troubleshoot phantomjs-node.

The answer to your original question is the answer from the phantomjs faq: No. Phantom and node have irreconcilable differences. Both expect to have complete control over fundamental low-level functionality like the event loop, the network stack, and JS execution so they can't cooperate within the same process.

Comment: wow that's nasty! so then the next question is: what's the best way to scrape a dynamic page using jquery?

Comment: @abbood I don't think it's possible. What is your goal here?

Comment: why wouldn't it be possible? i think i found my [answer](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/) though.. as always.. i start by taking the impossibly hard route, only to find a much easier solution lol.. i'll give you the correct answer award..

Comment: It would be possible if you stuck a complete DOM and JS runtime implementation inside jQuery but I didn't think that was a feasible solution.

Comment: it is! and it's working like a charm for me right now.. simply dump your raw html into a Dom structure.. use jquery magic to traverse it.. and everybody is happy! look at my outraged update to my question above ;)

Comment: @abbood Can you tell how to install jsdom for windows ?

Comment: @xpertgun i hate windows with a passion man so there is not much help i can offer you there i'm afraid

Comment: @abbood this may bee too late but it is possible to scrape dynamic webpages by using the injectJs method of the page object.

Comment: I have rewritten `phantom-node` and leading the effort to fix all bugs. Give v2 a try and let me know.

Answer (score 9):

You could also give [phridge](https://github.com/peerigon/phridge) a try. Your example would've been written like this:

```
var phantom;

// spawn a new PhantomJS process
phridge.spawn()
    .then(function (ph) {
        phantom = ph;
        return phantom.openPage("http://www.google.com");
    })
    .then(function (page) {
        return page.run(function () {
            // this function runs inside PhantomJS with this bound to a webpage instance
            return this.title;
        });
    })
    .then(function (title) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + title);
        // terminates the process cleanly
        phantom.dispose();
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

I am now the new maintainer for `phantom-node` package. It doesn't use coffeescript anymore. You can do something like

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
    page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function(status) {
      console.log(status);
      page.property('content').then(function(content) {
        console.log(content);
        page.close();
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The new version is much faster and resilient. It also doesn't use websockets anymore.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to this, and it will be working:

```
 var phantom = require('phantom');
 phantom.create(function(ph) {
   ph.createPage(function(page) {
     page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
       console.log("opened google? ", status);
       page.evaluate((function() {
         return document.title;
       }), function(result) {
         console.log('Page title is ' + result);
         ph.exit();
       });
     });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just ditch PhantomJS like I did because it was just too much a pain with these wrappers not working well, and go with [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) which is pretty popular too.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is working..

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
    page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function(status) {
      console.log(status);
      page.property('content').then(function(content) {
        console.log(content);
        page.close();
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But I am trying to generate an html page with some external script file. It is unable to inject a script file. I tried like following. Callback is not returning from the line `page.injectJs('./jQuery.min.js',function() {`

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

    phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
      ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.injectJs('./jQuery.min.js', function() {
          page.property('content').then(function(content) {
            console.log(content);
            page.close();
            ph.exit();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problems as you do, and apparently, there is a [known issue](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/issues/77) with `phantomjs-node` and newer versions of nodejs. Seems like it stopped working somewhere around node 0.9.3, according to the comments in the issue. So until that has been resolved, you either have to downgrade nodejs, or try a different module, like [node-phantom](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom), or just use `exec/spawn`.