# Casperjs login: Does casperjs manage cookies?

Tags: cookies, casperjs

I want my casper to log in and stay logged in during the session. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? Or do you need some more clarification? @Euphe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907800/how-to-persist-cookies-between-different-casperjs-processes

Answer (score 21):

If you want to store cookies in CasperJS, you can use the [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) cookiejar, which is accesible natively through CasperJS.

Simply add following option when you launch CasperJS:

```
--cookies-file=cookies.txt
```

Your cookies will be stored in that file. Even after exiting CasperJS, if you call CasperJS with this option, you'll have access to those cookies again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The cookies don't get written into the file.

Comment: If you launch CasperJS with the option like this: "casperjs test --cookies-file=cookies.txt scraper.js" it should definetly work. What version of PhantomJS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean?  are you just sitting idle in session?  Typically you do not want `casper.exit()` to be called.   So if there are times you want to wait a bit but stay logged in you should define that time in a

```
casper.wait(60000, function () {
});
```

Comment: Let's say casper submitted a login form, logged in. If casper navigates to a different page, does it stay logged in? If I restart casper, will it stay logged in after reconnecting?

Comment: No if you restart CasperJS it will kill your existing session and cache.