# How to visit website that need user login with cookies on casperjs

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, casperjs

I had been confusing for several days about using cookies with Casperjs.
I need to get the HTML,**which is generated by JavaScript and it also need user login**.So I tried to use Casperjs.
I tried to use Mylogin.js to login the website and get cookies to use afterwards.

```
casperjs.bat --cookies-file=cookie.txt --web-security=false Mylogin.js
```

Then I need to use GetHTML.js with cookies to visit some pages that need the user login.

```
casperjs.bat --cookies-file=cookie.txt --web-security=false GetHTML.js
```

But it seems that the cookies didn't work,it still need me login.I also tried to write cookies to file,and there isn't any help.

I Google it,read the document but no help.Need your help.Thanks

=====================================

Really thanks，I should the bin/casperjs.exe ,it works.

Comment: What is your CasperJS version? A couple of years ago there was an error that prevented CLI arguments from being passed from CasperJS to PhantomJS. Nowadays (version 1.1-beta3) there's casperjs.exe in bin folder that you should use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16954187/502860