# Amazon Login Phantom JS

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I’m pretty new at PhantomJS and programming in general, so please bear with me. I’m trying to write a code to login to my Amazon account, and add shipping addresses to my address book. The code I’m using is here:

```
var steps=[];
var loadInProgress = false;//This is set to true when a page is still loading

/*********SETTINGS*********************/


var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64)      AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;//Script is much faster with this field set to false
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;

/*********SETTINGS END*****************/

console.log('All settings loaded, start with execution');  
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
/**********DEFINE STEPS THAT FANTOM SHOULD DO***********************/
steps = [

     //Step 1 - Open Amazon home page
     function(){
         console.log('Step 1 - Open Amazon home page');
         page.open("https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/account/address/view.html?ie=UTF8&ref_=myab_view_new_address_form&viewID=newAddress&", function(status){      
         });
     },

     //Fill out login info
     function(){
         console.log('Step 2 - Populate and submit the login form');
         page.evaluate(function(){
             document.getElementById("ap_email").value= "my email";
             document.getElementById("ap_password").value="my password";
             document.getElementById("signInSubmit").click();
         });
     },

     //Write out webpage
         function(){
             var fs = require('fs');
             var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                     return document.querySelectorAll("html")[0].outerHTML;
                 });
             fs.write('AmazonPage1.html',result,'w');

         },

     //Fill out shipping info
         function(){
             console.log('Step 3 - Populate and submit the shpping info');
             page.evaluate(function(){

                 document.getElementById("enterAddressFullName").value= "name";
                 document.getElementById("enterAddressAddressLine1").value="address";
                 document.getElementById("enterAddressCity").value="city";
                 document.getElementById("enterAddressStateOrRegion").value="state";
                 document.getElementById("enterAddressPostalCode").value="zip";
                 document.getElementById("enterAddressPhoneNumber").value="phone";

                 document.getElementById("myab_newAddressButton").click();
             });

     },

     //Write out webpage
         function(){
             var fs = require('fs');
             var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                     return document.querySelectorAll("html")[0].outerHTML;
                 });
             fs.write('AmazonPage2.html',result,'w');

         }

     ];
/**********END STEPS THAT FANTOM SHOULD DO***********************/



//Execute steps one by one
interval = setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep,50); 

var testindex = 0;

function executeRequestsStepByStep(){
    if (loadInProgress == false && typeof steps[testindex] == "function" ) {
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }

    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }

}

/**
 * These listeners are very important in order to phantom work properly. Using these listeners, we control loadInProgress marker which controls, weather a page is fully loaded.
 * Without this, we will get content of the page, even a page is not fully loaded.
 */
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('Loading started');
};
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log('Loading finished');
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

Sometimes it works, but most of the time I get a captcha or a message from Amazon saying “Please Enable Cookies to Continue”. This post ([Amazon Seller Central Login Scrape PhantomJS + CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078639/amazon-seller-central-login-scrape-phantomjs-casperjs)) seems to maybe have some solution but I’m having a little trouble making sense of it. Can anyone explain in somewhat more lay terms how to accomplish this without getting any problems from Amazon?

Also a few other questions if you don’t mind:
I’m running this code locally from my home… so is my IP address now on some Amazon “suspicious IP list"? Can/would they ban my account for this??? I’d hate to lose my account over something like this. Maybe I should use a proxy? Is there something better than PhantomJS to use for this?

Sorry for the loaded question and thanks!

Comment: I'm the guy who asked the last one. I've been making Amazon backed scrapers for years and have yet to solve the problem completely. If I ever figure it out, I'll tell the world. I still get captchas every few months.  Yes they will ban your home IP and you'll be SOL. I use EC2 elastic IPs.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for commenting. Is there an advantage to using elastic IPs over say, a private proxy? Also, they might ban your IP but will they ban your account? For example, if they notice that a certain account is often associated with that IP.

Comment: I've never had an account banned. But I have had a captcha on the user account instead of the IP. where I no matter what computer I used I had to solve the captcha. As long as your rotating IPs you should be ok, however the problem with rotating IP services is that they might already be blocked :/

Comment: Hey Sean (or anyone)... why not use Selenium in conjunction with using a proxy IP. Seems like that would bypass these problems?

Comment: It's all the same.  Phantom and Selenium are both virtual browsers, and if one can get blocked so can the other.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Phantom is a headless browser, Selenium is a browser DRIVER, in that it boots up an actual browser. There is still detection methods but they can be avoided with Selenium I think.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem in EC2. It seems that the AWS cloud blocks ALL requests with Phantomjs as the user agent. You should try changing the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

I think amazon sends cookie via images too. So don't disable image loading. Make sure you are moving from one page to another only after the page loaded completely. Here is [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39852337#answer-41161835) for the captcha issue.