# Make GET request, run script on requested page, and return new HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, get, httprequest

I need a way using NodeJS to make a request to a url, run some Javascript on that page, and return the HTML generated after the Javascript executes. How would I do this?

For example:

GET `http://SiteToRequest.com`

Run `clickThis(); clickThat(); setAttribute();` on `http://SiteToRequest.com`

And then `return` the HTML scraped after the JS has run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js itself doesn't provide a browser runtime environment, but there's phantomjs (and the phantom-node integration package for node.js) that does. There's also http://zombie.js.org/ but I have no experience with it.

See [can phantomjs work with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745394/can-phantomjs-work-with-node-js) where the maintainer of phantom-node explains how to use it